# how to get specific group in regex

Tags: regex

Can anybody please help me to get specific group value out of all the group values.

In below given string I have to fetch specific IPs like first IP or second IP or third. Now I wrote the regex to match the IP value but it does not gives me the specific one.

Example String:

```
management:10.103.2.1/52488 (10.105.1.50/52488) to a Identity b:10.105.1.53/443 (10.105.1.53/443)
```

My Regex:

`\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`

By applying this ip address selects all the ip address while I want to select specific ip address in the string like(first ip address in the string or second ip address in the string and so on)

Comment: “but it does not gives me the specific one” What does it give you then? Show what you tried (**code**) and what you got.

Comment: @Holger By applying this regex.. it will select all the ipadress in the string not the specif one. And I want to select specif ip address.

Comment: Maybe you apply the regex wrong. We could help if you would show us how you apply it.

Comment: But your regex does not match multiple IP-addresses. So it does not have anything to do with groups. If you want to find a specific one call `Matcher.find` `n` times to find the `n`'th occurrence. If you have a more specific question, *ask it*.

Comment: @Holger I know with help of programming I can achieve it..But I am looking for specific regex.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind. Let me be more specific, if u can help me to extract 3rd ipaddress of the string using regex, as it will solve my problems

Comment: @mahesh then don’t tag your question with `[java]` if you don’t want to do Java programming.

Comment: @mahesh basically create a regex that is build this way (IP == your current regex): .*IP.*IP.*(IP).*

Comment: @Absurd-Mind that would always find the last address. Remember that `.*` greedily matches anything.

Comment: @Holger yes, it should be something like this .*?IP.*?IP.*?(IP).*

Comment: @Absurd-Mind and then you are at what my answer contains. the only difference is that I use `{n}` instead of `n` repetitions of the pattern within the regex. I prefer my version as the pattern is rather long already

Answer (score 1):

If you refuse to use the simple logic of invoking `find` as many times as you wish inside your software, you can find the `n`'th occurrence of a pattern `p` but applying it `n` times within the pattern prepended with *reluctant* matched arbitrary text `(?:.*?p){n}` where `n` is the desired nimber and `p` the pattern. So in your case the pattern is:

```
(?:.*?\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}
```

to find the third IP-address. The four groups you have already defined will contain the four decimal numbers of the last match, read third IP-address, after a successful `find` operation. Of course, if you want a complete `String` for the entire address you can enclose your four groups with another group. It would be group `1` then.

Comment: The answer that you given does not gives me the ip address instead it gives me whole string like "management:10.103.2.1/52488 (10.105.1.50/52488) to a Identity b:10.105.1.53". Which is of on use..I want to extract only ip address..

Comment: Maybe you should read the entire answer. I told you that the *groups 1 to 4* will give you the numbers of the IP address. I also told you how to get the entire IP address as a single string if you want it.